# View connected to UITabBarController not displaying tab bar

Tags: swift, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller

I have a `UITabBarController`. Originally I had it connected to 4 `UINavigationController`s and each tab would function as expected. Each would navigate to the appropriate view and the tab bar would remain visible allowing the user to switch between tabs.

Now I wanted to connect another `UINavigationController` to the `UITabBarController`; essentially creating a fifth tab. I connected the `UITabBarController` to the new `UINavigationController` using a Relationship Segue successfully creating a fifth tab. However, when the fifth tab is pressed, the view is shown but there is no tab bar, thus preventing the user from navigating to any other screen.

The Bottom Bar setting is set to 'Inferred' just like the other views but it still does not show the tab bar. Why is the tab bar not showing and how can I make it appear?

Note that the UIViewController not displaying the tab bar has connections to it from other View Controllers but I don't see why this would affect the tab bar displaying.

Comment: I have been testing a few things and managed to get the tab bar to appear if I connect the UITabBarController directly to the UIViewController, essentially bypassing the UINavigationController.

However, now when I click a button on the UIViewController to segue to another view, the view appears but it doesn't show the navigation bar so there is no way to navigate back from this page. All my other tabs seem to work as expected except for this one.

Answer (score 1):

Silly error on my part. The check box to Hide Bottom Bar When Pushed was checked so unchecking this solved the problem.